# Django: model does not render fields correctly in Admin

Tags: django

I've a model that I know is recording correctly the values in DataBase, but it is not showing them correctly in Admin Panel.

I know it's saving this fields correctly because:

1.- I can Query the model in Shell and see the values correctly.
2.- I'm using this model's fields to create another model, and this other model saves correctly and SHOWs correctly it's fields in Admin Panel.

**What could be wrong?**

**Shell**:

```
>>> SizeQuantity.objects.get(pk=9)
<SizeQuantity: variante_125 por cantidad_200>
>>> SizeQuantity.objects.get(pk=9).size
'variante_125'
>>> SizeQuantity.objects.get(pk=9).quantity
'cantidad_200'
```

What I see in AdminPanel:

[image]

This is my other model that uses values from SizeQuantiy:

I was expecting to render the Size and Quantity fields like this for my SizeQuantity model:

[image]

```
from .models import Cart, SizeQuantity
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Cart)
admin.site.register(SizeQuantity)
```

**models.py**:

```
class SizeQuantity(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAMANIOS)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CANTIDADES)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " - " + str(self.size) + " por " + str(self.quantity)

    @property
    def image_filename(self):
        return self.image.url.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: if you pass CHOICES to a CharField, you're forcing it to a select dropdown.

Comment: @Toby I think django admin automatically show choices to dropdown, isn't it?

Comment: I believe so - same with the form in a template. If you have a fixed list of predefined choices, you shouldn't be entering that choice via a text input.

Comment: @Toby You're right and I'm not the questioner. I think he can figured out easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Django can't render your fields correctly because mentioned values are not included in fields choices (`TAMANIOS` `CANTIDADES`)

Answer (score 1):

Your field above ('variante_125', 'cantidad_200') is not in your valid CHOICES.

You can add any char for size and quantity fields although you don't write the values in CHOICES. But you can't use the choices such as `get_FOO_display`. It's helpful to check docs here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices).

You should check TAMANIOS, CANTIDADES choices that have those values.